# "Run | Debug" option missing in older TestNG projects in Eclipse using TestNG and Selenium

Tags: eclipse, testng

I've recently created some new TestNG projects in Eclipse and discovered to my delight :) the "new" Run | Debug decorations. The work great for me. Unfortunately, my old project do not display the decorations. How can I cause these useful buttons to display in ALL my TestNG projects?[image]